how does Azure AKS GitOps decides which cluster directory to bootstrap from?
Most "flux boostrap" CLI examples show the usage of a parameter "--path" to point to a directory like `/clusters/staging" to bootstrap the config from.
When using the Azure Portal AKS GitOps page, there is no way to specify the cluster "path" . Only the "paths" of the different kustomoizations can be created, but on all examples they do not point to "clusters/xxx" but to either "./base/staging" or "./infrastructure".
Is there some "hidden logic", which chooses the "cluster" directory to bootstrap from ?
I looked in all AKS Flux tutorials, but did not find any hint,

AKS GitOps does not have any hidden logic to choose the cluster directory to bootstrap from. When using the Azure Portal GitOps page, the "path" parameter is not used to specify the cluster directory. Instead, the "paths" of the different kustomizations are created, which represent the set of manifests that Flux should reconcile to the cluster. These kustomizations are Flux resources, each associated with a path in the repository.

The "path" parameter is used to specify the path to the directory containing the Kubernetes manifests in the repository. Therefore, the "path" parameter is not used to specify the cluster directory, but rather the directory containing the Kubernetes manifests.

Yes, thank you for this confirmation.
So the Microsoft tutorial here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/tutorial-use-gitops-flux2?tabs=azure-cli
which points to this GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/gitops-flux2-kustomize-helm-mt
is somehow misleading, because its "structured" and the "clusters" directory:
https://github.com/Azure/gitops-flux2-kustomize-helm-mt/tree/main/clusters
is "unused".
But would it at least work, when I created in portal a kustomization with the path "clusters/staging"  instead of "apps/staging" as the tutorial does ?

It seem that this file:
https://github.com/Azure/gitops-flux2-kustomize-helm-mt/blob/main/clusters/staging/apps.yaml
"points back" to "apps/staging"  ?

Your understanding is correct, the doc you referred to uses a structured directory with a clusters directory, but it’s not required by the Azure Portal GitOps configuration. As discussed in comments, when using the Azure Portal to configure GitOps for AKS, there is no hidden logic that automatically chooses the “cluster” directory to bootstrap from. Instead, the configuration relies on the paths you specify for kustomizations during creation. When using the flux bootstrap via CLI, you specify the --path
flux bootstrap github \
  --owner=<naveen> \
  --repository=<https://github.com/naveen/naveen-codes> \
  --branch=main \
  --path=./clusters/staging


But in Azure portal the process is abstracted. You specify the repository URL, branch, and kustomization paths manually.
For example, let’s say you have a flux config file clusters/staging/kustomization.yaml
In your portal go to your cluster-> Gitops-> add config->Fill the details like name, namespace, repo url, branch -> add kustomization-> (here is where you put your path) and create.


